# continue writing on same XML file without deleting in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

I have done this code so far works well, but the only issue is that the XML file gets deleted every time I use the method addUser, I want the code to continue writing under it

**the code I wrote in c#:**

```
 public static void AddUser(PersonData pd)
        {
            XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\PersonData.Xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            xWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xWriter.WriteStartElement("User");
            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("idNumber", pd.IdNumber1);

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Firstname");
            xWriter.WriteString(pd.FirstName1);
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();//<FirstName>

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("LastName");
            xWriter.WriteString(pd.LastName1);
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();//<LastName>

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("DateOfBirth");
            xWriter.WriteString(pd.DateOfBirth1.ToString());
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();//<DateOfBirth>

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Address");
            xWriter.WriteString(pd.Address1);
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();//<Address>

            xWriter.WriteEndElement();//<user>
            xWriter.Close();
        }
```

**the XML output:**

```
<User idNumber="316447077">
  <Firstname>majd</Firstname>
  <LastName>sadi</LastName>
  <DateOfBirth>29/03/1998 14:54:50</DateOfBirth>
  <Address>hohos</Address>
</User>
```

**the XML output that I want to do:**

```
 <User idNumber="316447077">
      <Firstname>majd</Firstname>
      <LastName>sadi</LastName>
      <DateOfBirth>29/03/1998 14:54:50</DateOfBirth>
      <Address>hohos</Address>
    </User>
    <User idNumber="316447077">
      <Firstname>majd</Firstname>
      <LastName>sadi</LastName>
      <DateOfBirth>29/03/1998 14:54:50</DateOfBirth>
      <Address>hohos</Address>
    </User>
```

Comment: did you try to flush like `xWriter.Flush()` after you write your end element?

Comment: also looks like you don't have a `StartDocument`, `EndDocument` and in case you are appending to the existing file, you have to traverse to the last user and then append the new data after the existing one by selecting the root and appending the new element as a child node.
Also try wrapping the writer in a `using(...) {... }` block for better management of resource.

Comment: Well formed xml has only one tag at the root.  Appending to an xml is not well formed but it is allowed according to the xml specification.   So you will not have well formed xml which I do not have any issue and is often done with log file and streaming data.  To append use following :             FileStream stream = File.Open("D:\\PersonData.Xml", FileMode.Append);
            XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a root node to your XML (not valid XML without it), you could do this with XElement:

```
XElement xe;

if (File.Exists("D:\\PersonData.Xml"))
  xe = XElement.Load("D:\\PersonData.Xml");
else
  xe = new XElement("Users");

XElement newUser = new XElement("User");
newUser.Add(new XAttribute("idNumber", pd.IdNumber1));
newUser.Add(new XElement("Firstname", pd.FirstName1));
newUser.Add(new XElement("LastName", pd.LastName1));
newUser.Add(new XElement("DateOfBirth", pd.DateOfBirth1.ToString()));
newUser.Add(new XElement("Address", pd.Address1));

xe.Add(newUser);
xe.Save("D:\\PersonData.Xml");
```

Comment: how can I make a root element so every time I use the AddUser method, the new User XElement goes inside the root element

Comment: @majd-sadi updated to have it create the file (if it doesn't already exist) with a root node of "Users"

Comment: This is not recommended if you are opening and closing the file lots of times.  Using this method for creating log files gets slower and slower every time you add one item.  Suppose you have 10,000 entries in a log file and are adding one more. You have to and read the entire file and then add item, and finally write the file.

Comment: @jdweng I agree, but this doesn't look to be a log file.  It looks to be a small user file.  XElement won't be a performance issue here.

Comment: At least somebody agrees with me.  Most people say there is an error when there are more than one root tag.  The results in this case could be streaming data or data from a database where each row is in xml format.  With large data coming Async, you do not want to wait for all the data to be receive before post processing.

Answer (score 1):

try to flush like xWriter.Flush() after you write your end element?